# Find exact value of trig function

Tags: trigonometry

How would I get the exact value for this equation?

Question: Find $\arcsin\left[\sin\left(\dfrac{5\pi}{4}\right)\right]$.

The answer they give me is: $-\dfrac{\pi}{4}$.

I know how to get the decimal value but not the exact value form.

Comment: Refer to [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) post for information on formatting with MathJax

Comment: Do you know the domain and range of the arcsine function?

Comment: First of all, you have to understand that the arcsine is actually the inverse of the sine function. Secondly, you should be aware that while the argument of the sine can be any value on the real axis, the inverse is chosen in the interval $(-\pi/2, \pi/2)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is good to notice that the arcsine function has a range of $[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]$, therefore the arcsine function is only defined on this interval. Normally a function that is not monotonic cannot have an inverse function, but since the sine function has a period of $2 \pi$, this is possible. This is due to the sine function's role in the unit circle; more information can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine#Inverse) . Therefore
$$
\sin\left(-\frac{\pi}{4}\right) = \sin\left(\frac{5\pi}{4}\right)
$$

It is also good to note that

$$
f^{-1}(f(x)) = f(f^{-1}(x)) = x
$$

Having $f^{-1}(x)$ being the inverse function of $f(x)$

But due to the properties of the sine function, All real values that the arcsine function yield are less than $\frac{\pi}{2}$ and greater than $-\frac{\pi}{2}$

Comment: The range of arcsine is a closed interval, not open, so the parentheses should be square.  It is defined on its domain, which is $[-1,1]$

Answer (score 1):

Recall that for an invertible function $f$ with its inverse denoted by $f^{-1}$,  for all $x$ in the domain of $f$ we have $f^{-1}(f(x))=x$. Thus, if you can show that $\sin\frac{5\pi}{4}=\sin\frac{-\pi}{4}$ then you can apply the aforementioned property of inverse functions (since $\arcsin$ is the inverse of $\sin$) to get the correct answer. Hint: to show that $\sin\frac{5\pi}{4}=\sin\frac{-\pi}{4}$ first note that $\sin\frac{5\pi}{4}=\sin{\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+\pi\right)}$.

Answer (score 0):

The function $f(x) = \sin x$ does not have an inverse since it is not injective (one-to-one).  To obtain an inverse, we restrict its domain so that it is injective.  The standard restriction is

$$g(x) = \sin x, -\frac{\pi}{2} \leq x \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$$

Since $g(x)$ is injective, it has an inverse.  The domain of $g(x)$ is $D_g = \left[-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}\right]$ and its range is $R_g = [-1, 1]$.  The inverse of $g(x)$ is

$$g^{-1}(x) = \arcsin x$$

which has domain $D_{g^{-1}} = [-1, 1]$ and range $R_{g^{-1}} = \left[-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}\right]$.

Since the arcsine function has range $\left[-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}\right]$, we must find the unique angle $\theta \in \left[-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}\right]$ such that $\sin\theta = \sin\left(\frac{5\pi}{4}\right)$.

**Method 1:**

\begin{align*}
\arcsin\left[\sin\left(\frac{5\pi}{4}\right)\right] & = \arcsin\left[-\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\right] && \text{since $\dfrac{5\pi}{4}$ is a third-quadrant angle}\\
& = \arcsin\left(-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right) && \text{evaluate $\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)$}\\
& = -\frac{\pi}{4}
\end{align*}

since $-\dfrac{\pi}{4}$ is the unique angle $\theta$ in the interval $\left[-\dfrac{\pi}{2}, \dfrac{\pi}{2}\right]$ such that $\sin\theta = -\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$.

**Method 2:**

\begin{align*}
\arcsin\left[\sin\left(\frac{5\pi}{4}\right)\right] & = \arcsin\left[-\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\right] && \text{since $\dfrac{5\pi}{4}$ is a third-quadrant angle}\\
& = \arcsin\left[\sin\left(-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\right]  && \text{since sine is an odd function}\\
& = -\frac{\pi}{4} && \text{since $(g^{-1} \circ g)(x) = x$ for $x \in D_g$}
\end{align*}